# Xcode building different environments for the same app

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have an app that talks to a server. I have 2 versions of this server: a production one and a testing one. This means I'd need to have a production iOS app and a testing iOS app. The logic is essentially the same for both versions of the app, except it would need to use certain configurations depending on which server it connects to. Right now, my solution is to use a `plist` file that contains informations that the 2 versions need. The `plist` would contain a bunch of key-value pairs like:

```
url: test-server.domain.com
username: test-subject
password: test-password
```

I have 2 git branches: a production branch and a testing branch for each of the iOS app version. The content of the said `plist` file would be different on each branch.

Question is: is there a more elegant way to solve this? Preferably I'd like to only have 1 branch. I've looked into using Xcode's environment variables, but those don't stick when I archive/build my apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use `Preprocessor Macros` for this.

Define variable like `DEBUG` for Debug and nothing in Release.

[image]

And then use this like

```
enum AppConfig {
    case debug
    case testFlight
    case appStore

    var host: String {
        switch self {
            case .debug: return "test host"
            default: return "production host"
        }
    }

    static var current: AppConfiguration {
        #if DEBUG
            return .debug
        #else
            if Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL?.lastPathComponent == "sandboxReceipt" {
                return .testFlight
            } else {
                return .appStore
            }
        #endif
    }
}
```

Wherever you want to use host, you can use `AppConfig.current.host`. The only thing you need to do is create scheme for debug and release.

Comment: This sounds cool! Follow up question: can I make different schemes for each preprocessor macros? I assume that'd be where I set the value of each preprocessor macros?

Answer (score 2):

There sure is! You can do this with environment variables, as described in this blogpost: [Flavors for iOS](http://onebigfunction.com/ios/2017/03/14/flavor-ios/). You can even switch app icon and app name based on the variables when building, therefore, you can check in code in the following way: `if #APP_DEV // call dev API ELSIF // call prod API`.

### Steps

1: On the project settings level, duplicate the debug configuration and rename it to staging. (Optional)

2: Open the project build settings and add some user-defined settings: `APP_ENV` with values dev => dev, staging => stage, production => prod.

3: You need multiple bundle IDs to load apps side by side (for instance a beta or production app). Therefor, create another user-defined settings `APP_BUNDLE_SUFFIX` with the value  `.$(APP_ENV:lower)`. This turns `Dev` into `.dev`. Leave production empty if you like to have no extra suffix when submitting the app.

4: Append the `APP_BUNDLE_SUFFIX` to your product bundle ID (`com.testapp.YourCoolApp.$(APP_BUNDLE_SUFFIX)`).

5: In Swift projects, you can add the added variables to the "Active Compilation Conditions" on the same screen. Do this by adding `ENV_$(APP_ENV)` to the environments listed. In Objective-C projects, this can be done by adding the environments to the "Preprocessor macro's", but pay attention, you'll need to suffix `=1` to the value in order to activate the variables.

### Making the env vars stick

You might need to create separate schemes to achieve this. You can duplicate schemes, or `option+click` on the scheme at the top and switch the build config.

Comment: Link-only answers are far from ideal here. Links go bad over time. An answer should at least summarize the basic tasks involved so it remains useful even if the link goes bad.

Comment: I agree with you on that, but then I think the question is too broad. If I have to summarize that entire blogpost, then it would be large enough to cover a book, haha.

Comment: If you think the question is too broad then don't answer it and vote to close as too broad. But if you do answer, you need to post a useful answer.

Comment: I edited the answer, so the down vote might be removed.

Comment: You mean you edited the answer to make it better, not just so who ever down voted it might come back and remove the vote (it wasn't me).

Comment: I only saw the down vote after editing, so that wasn't my motive. :)

Comment: I don't think this improves the answer. All you're doing now is effectively quoting the original blog post, which you didn't write. It's gone now from link-only to a kind of copy-and-paste. This was _always_ best as a mere comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I used a source I knew, it covers precisely what TS wants, so what is the problem? This is very discouraging attitude and I certainly regret remotely trying to answer this question now. I am trying to make an effort here, but please, show me how you want me to answer if it doesn't fit the requirements!

Comment: I honestly found the answer @jbehrens94 posted very useful... I'm no SO expert and I'm not sure what the proper way to answer these type of (broad-ish) questions is, but it certainly helped me in one form or another and I'm sure future readers will feel the same way. Thanks jbehrens94 for  your effort.